# Can't draw on HTML5 canvas using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

The following code won't load the green rectangle in the canvas.  This is my very first time trying out jQuery (either it sucks or me sucks), why such a simple thing is not working, I'm baffled.  My web browser is Firefox 3.6. Playing with jQuery because there's another jQuery-driven piece of code that could be quite useful...

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 #canvas {
 border:1px solid black;
 }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
// have also tried
<script type="application/javascript">

  $(function() {
 var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 // ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
 ctx.fillStyle = "green";
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,50,50);

 });

</script> 
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try wrapping your code in a plain old anonymous function? jQuery is really not much use with `<canvas>`

Comment: In the future, don't use `&lt;` and `<pre>` to display your code. Just indent it all by 4 spaces and it will be in a code block and syntax highlighted too

Answer (score 4):

Getting the canvas element by using jQuery won't work.  You can't use the getContext() method on the jQuery object.  Instead of:

`var canvas = $("#canvas");`

You should use (if "draw" was the ID of the canvas element):

`var canvas = document.getElementById('draw');`

Comment: To get the native DOM element you can also write: `var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];` or `var canvas = $("#canvas").get(0);`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
        if (canvas.getContext) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            // Choose a color
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support CANVAS
        }
    });
</script>
```

That should work as expected. I suspect you were missing the $(document).ready() bit.

Comment: No. still blank canvas.  I added 
alert('poblem'); 
to the else block

Is my copy of FF hacked or my computer hacked?

Comment: How to test if jquery is actually functioning correctly? tks.

Comment: It works with Chrome 5.0.  But jquery is so freaking picky?

The following code won't work with firebug lite on chrome thou
it complained about undefined

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  // console.log(e.keycode); 
  alert(e.keycode);
})

Answer (score 1):

Don Don,

You need to make two small changes.

First remove the [0] from this line,

```
var canvas = $("#canvas")[0]
```

Second, take that [0] and add it to the if statement,

```
if (canvas[0].getContext) {
```

And add it to the assignment of ctx

```
var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
```

Alternatively assign it to a variable before you test for it.

```
var canvas = $("#canvas"), ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
if (ctx) {
```

And you should be good to go...

Answer (score 0):

You should close the canvas tag and as Nick already said, you should definitely use the jQuery $(document).ready() function:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #canvas {
        border:1px solid black;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
        if (canvas.getContext) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            // Choose a color
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support CANVAS
        }
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
                var ctx = $("#canvas")[0].getContext("2d");
                // Choose a color
                ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
                ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
                ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 200);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I duplicate the problem in IE and solve it.
The reason is the script tag must use the explicit close tag.
So change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

(browser does not understand <script ... />)

there is another syntax issue is the canvas element does not have close tag, but browser (IE) seems to understand it. Not sure FF

Comment: and there is a good reason for that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work